# 2D: How do I make animated objects follow another animated object?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I have four stroke objects that each have their own short, looping animation and want them to follow another stroke object.  My plan wasn't to automate it too much (of course that would be desirable), I was hoping I could select all four and move them together as a group and follow the main object.

I tried doing this in object mode, but it doesn't seem to be committed to the key frames.  I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: I think I hacked it.  Since I could move them together in Object Mode, I made keyframes using the Transform context menu (the orange box thing) and held it near the object I wanted it to follow for each frame.  It's not pretty, but I don't have to do it for many frames of a hand-drawn animation.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access these new keyframes because I don't see them on the Dope Sheet, but I'm not going to question it for now.